# Parametrize the intersection of 2 planes.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Parametrize the intersection of $\frac {x^2} {3}+y^2+\frac {z^2} {10} = 1$ with $z=2$ (level curve) plane.

Here is what I did.
Plugged in $z=2$ into the plane $\frac {x^2} {3}+y^2+\frac 25=1$. I got $y^2=9-5x^2$ Then I substituted $y^2$ into the plane $\frac {x^2} {3}+9-5x^2+\frac25=1$ to solve for $x^2$. I got $x^2=1.8$ and then got $y=0$. How should I parametrize the intersection from here onward?

$\mathbf Error$ in my calculation, $y^2=\frac 35-\frac{x^2}{3}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started out correctly, by plugging $z = 2$ into the equation and finding $\frac{x^2}{3} + y^2 + \frac{2}{5} = 1$, or

$$\frac{x^2}{3} + y^2 = \frac{3}{5}.$$

The next step is to put the equation in the standard form for an ellipse. (Recall that the standard form is $\frac{(x - h)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y - k)^2}{b^2} = 1$.)

\begin{align}
\frac{5}{3} \cdot \frac{x^2}{3} + \frac{5}{3} \cdot y^2 &= \frac{5}{3} \cdot \frac{3}{5} \\
\frac{x^2}{\frac{9}{5}} + \frac{y^2}{\frac{3}{5}} &= 1
\end{align}

Here we have $h = k = 0$, $a = \sqrt{\frac{9}{5}} = \frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}$, and $b = \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$. The next step is to parametrize the ellipse, and recall that the parametrization for the $z$ coordinate is $z(t) = 2$.

Comment: I got $x(t)=\sqrt3cos(t)$ and $y(t)=sin(t)$. so the parametric equation is $\mathbf{\{\sqrt3cos(t), sin(t), 2\}}$?

Comment: Dear @user95087, you have the right idea, however your answer would be incorrect due to a mistake I made in my original post - please see my edited post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you have make something wrong.Plugged in $z=2$ into the plane $\frac {x^2} {3}+y^2+\frac 25=1$. You should get $y^2=\frac{3}{5}-\frac{x^2}{3}$,  rather than  $y^2=9-5x^2$ this is the equation of the curve while $z=2$